# Patch vs Compartment

Tags: word-choice, differences

I want to describe the application of finite element method. In this method, we divide an existing function into small parts and assume these parts are constant.

Which is the best way to describe these parts? Do I take *a patch* or *a compartment*?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is on-topic on ELU, since it deals with fairly specialized jargon. Maybe check out [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com), [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com), or [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the vocabulary of structural mechanics, not the English language.

Comment: @Xanne the question is more about the difference between a patch or a compartment. Which word is preferred when you cut a wooden block with some numbers on them? Do I paint the third patch or the third compartment, assuming I am not using the best word "piece". I can actually go for piece for my question as well, but I am reserving it for something else.

Comment: Oh, is a wooden block a function?

Comment: A patch is something you wear on your arm when you're trying to give up cigarettes.  A compartment is a place in your desk where you keep your cigarettes.  As far as I can tell, neither word makes any sense in the context of cutting a wooden block into pieces. VTC

Comment: @Scott what about a patch of land or patch of clothing? Patch has so many more meanings, but good luck with quitting smoking. Compartment means "a separate section of a structure or container in which certain items can be kept separate from others", but again good luck with quitting smoking. "Neither" is a legitimate answer as well, but this question is a valid question.

Comment: @Xanne I need a verbal explanation to divide something into smaller pieces.

Comment: @C.Koca: What about a patch of land or patch of clothing?  You seem to be admitting that, with the possible exception of the vocabulary of structural mechanics, the words have nothing to do with each other.  You might as well ask, “I'm a carpenter. Should I use the word *borrow* or the word *purple* ?” I believe that an answer of *neither* would [not even be wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite element method will separate a function into its *component parts* or it will break a function into distinct components or *elements*. Take these lecture notes explaining finite element method from Berkeley's Mechanical Engineering department:

> The finite element method (FEM) is the dominant discretization technique in structural
>   mechanics. The basic concept in the physical interpretation of the FEM is the subdivision
>   of the mathematical model into disjoint (non-overlapping) components of simple
>   geometry called finite elements or elements for short.

Edit: Per the comments, the OP has asked which, of *patch* or *compartment*, is better. I will suggest that, while neither is ideal, *compartment* is the better choice, as it is the only of the two that describes a *part of a whole* in this context.

*Compartment* can commonly be used to describe a physical location, such as a *cellular compartment* (e.g. organelle) or a *glove compartment* in a car.

*Patch* is more infrequently used to describe location in the context of a specialized purpose, such as a *briar patch* or a *patch of hair* and is harder to generalize.

For example, while *I have created a compartment in which to store my keys* is appropriate, *I have created a patch in which to store my keys* would not be used in normal speech or writing.

Comment: So, are you saying that neither *patch* nor *compartment* makes any sense in the context of this question? If that’s what you’re saying, then please say it.

Comment: Neither makes sense to me in this context, unless there's a technical nuance to the question that I'm not catching. I've never heard of patch or compartment being used to describe the result of a division.

Comment: I see. I've added an extra comment to my original answer to hopefully help address the question.

Comment: _Patch_ (noun and verb) also has a specific meaning in computer code, which would make it especially in inappropriate to use here.